# Display User Name PHP MySql

Tags: php, mysql, session, cookies

I'm doing a project at the moment and I'm trying to get a user name to display on pages when they login.
I've tried to echo the user name in various places but it won't work for me.
Could anyone tell me what code to enter and where please?

```
<?php 
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("project") or die(mysql_error()); 

if(isset($_COOKIE['ID_my_site'])) 

 { 

$username = $_COOKIE['ID_my_site']; 

$pass = $_COOKIE['Key_my_site']; 

$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'")or       die(mysql_error()); 

while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $check ))   

    { 

    if ($pass != $info['password']) 

        {           header("Location: login.php"); 

        } 

else 

        { 

         echo "Admin Area<p>"; 

echo "Your Content<p>"; 

echo "<a href=logout.php>Logout</a>"; 

        } 

    } 

    } 

else 

{            

header("Location: login.php"); 

} 

?>
```

Comment: did your COOKIE getting username

Comment: You could give the following anywhere inside your while-loop:

echo $info['username'];

Comment: Your mysql query is unsafe, use PDO if you're able. http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php And don't store any user data in a cookie, store a login token for example. Furthermore you're grabbing the username by searching your database with the username you already have? ID sounds like a number to me. If you would do everything right, you would fetch the username by `$info['username']`.

Comment: You should never store a password in a cookie. The username neither (except to make the next login easier). Use a session variable to store the data of the current user.

Comment: It has already been mentioned not to store passwords using cookies. However, if a user disables cookies on their computer, and in the event that you do fix your code for it to work, it will fail. It's better to use [**sessions**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a diagnostic idea, first see that you definately have a strig in the variable

```
echo ($username = $_COOKIE['ID_my_site']);
```

Once you definately have this you should be able to echo it further down in the html section

Answer (score 0):

if $username variable having email id then
Just select the username using your existing query.
then save in session variable or cookie.
then echo this session variable wherever you want.

or if $username variable having username then simply echo it.
echo ($username = $_COOKIE['ID_my_site']);